# Printing a wkhtmlpdf generated file in Java

Tags: java, printing, wkhtmltopdf

When I print a PDF File using Java, which has been generated using wkhtmltopdf, the text comes all corrupted.

Sample output can be seen below,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiCTS.png

Code with which I make PDF file,

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --page-width 72 --page-height 200 --margin-top 0 --margin-right 0 --margin-bottom 0 --margin-left 0 --encoding 'utf-8' [full_path_html] [full_path_pdf]
```

Code with which I print PDF,

```
PrintService service =  ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 50, 50, services, null, flavor, atts);

final PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPrintService(service);

PDDocument document = PDDocument.load([full_path_pdf]);
document.print(job);
document.close();
```

Comment: You need to put *some* kind of code in your question or we have no chance of helping.

Comment: Hi Todd, Pasted all the code!

Comment: So is the PDF corrupted or just the printed one? Can you try a different printer?

Comment: PDF works fine, when I print it using Adobe Acrobat Reader! So i think PDF is not corrupt!